# AngularJS/Javascript - How can I replace an entire object with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to update an `objectValue` with a JSON callback.
As per the code below, if i leave `objectValue.data` it only updates the value in the pair. I've tried taking the `.data` off but then it has no response.

Is there a way i can overwrite completely `objectValue` with the JSON request i get?

```
app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    var objectValue = {
        'data': 'Click to change'
    };
    return {
        setObject: function(value) {
            objectValue.data = value;
        },
        getObject: function() {
            return objectValue;
        }
    };
});
```

cheers!

Comment: what do you mean by 'it only updates the value in the pair'? whats your desired outcome?

Comment: i mean, when it updates it becomes 'data': {"json":{"bit":[{"keyname":"key","valuename":value},{"keyname":"key","valuename":value},{"keyname":"key","valuename":value}... and so on

id like it to scrap whats already there and only be left with my json as the object

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: not of my little monster, but i got the service part from http://jsfiddle.net/b2fCE/1/

Comment: What is your result now? And what are you trying to achieve? Still don't get it

Comment: after updating my object is { 'data': 'this stuff was updated' }, im trying to update the whole object, starting anew with { mynewjson etcetc

Comment: so how does the json look like?

Comment: something like {
    "toplevel": {
        "title1": [{
                    "keyname": "key",
                    "valuename": value
                }, {
                    "keyname": "key",
                    "valuename": value
                },  with about 6 different titles and their 50 or so children

Comment: so you call both setObject first, where you want to put your object instead of a value in - and then you call getObject, right?

Comment: right! i call setObject and wait for it on another point

Comment: I put an answer, don't see where your problem lies. Maybe set up a minimum jsfiddle so that we see better.

Comment: Is your question solved?

Comment: not really, i just went with item.data instead (not really what i wanted but works)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with this. I tried:

```
....    
// service
    setObject: function(value) {
        objectValue = value;
    },


// and in the controller
app.controller('myController', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
   $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString;
   $scope.objectValue = sharedProperties.getObject();
   $scope.setString = function(newValue) {
       $scope.objectValue.data = newValue;
       sharedProperties.setObject(newValue);
       alert(sharedProperties.getObject());
   };
});
```

And it alerts's the object. Maybe there is something wrong with another part of your code. Try to log/alert step by step and see what happens.